# Failed to execute 'only' on 'IDBKeyRange': The parameter is not a valid key

Tags: indexeddb

I am fetching data from indexeddb using where class using jsstore.I got response.But getting 
"Failed to execute 'only' on 'IDBKeyRange': The parameter is not a valid key. " console error.Why I am getting this error.can anyone pls help me.

```
//Get DBSchema(table & columns)
  private getDbSchema = function () {
    const tblArticle = {
      Name: this._indexedDBLiveDBTableName,
      Columns: [
       {
          Name: 'ParentName',
          NotNull: true,
          DataType: 'string'
        },
        {
          Name: 'ChildName',
          NotNull: true,
          DataType: 'string'
        }
        ,
        {
          Name: 'UpdatedDate',
          NotNull: true,
          DataType: 'string'
        }
      ]
    };

    const Database = {
      Name: this._indexedDBLiveDBName,
      Tables: [tblArticle]
    };
    return Database as any;
  };

 //Fetch articles From IndexedDB
GetArticleFromIndexedDb(section) {
    this._connection.openDb(this._indexedDBLiveDBName);
    return this._connection.select({
      From: this._indexedDBLiveDBTableName,
      Where: {
        ChildName: section
      }
    });
 }
```

value of section will be like "India","TamilNadu"

Kindly find the attached screenshot for error

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQmsx.png)

I am using **jsstore 1.3.0**

I updated jsstore version to 1.4.1 which is giving  "Maximum call stack size exceeded"

[image]

Thanks

Comment: What data are you passing to the `IDBKeyRange.only()` call? As noted in the error, you can only pass values which are valid Indexed DB keys (numbers, dates, strings, binary data, or arrays of other keys)

Comment: Please add your code with the console error screenshot.

Comment: What is the value of section ?

Comment: Can you update jsstore version? and see if the issue still persist.

Comment: updated jsstore version to 1.4.1 which is giving "Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Comment: in which browser ? Is it happening for this query or something else?

Comment: It is in chrome browser.I didn't use any other query.pls see screenshot

Comment: This is the error occuring when inserting values. It may be that you may be inserting many values at a time. You can use SkipDataCheck for get rid of this error (stack size exceeded). Check insert doc for more info - http://jsstore.net/Tutorial/insert

Comment: insert error gone.But fetch error "Failed to execute 'only' on 'IDBKeyRange': The parameter is not a valid key" remains the same.But I can fetch the data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162789/discussion-between-ujjwal-kumar-gupta-and-kamalav).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is due to the invalid value supplied. IndexedDB support list of value - numbers, dates, strings, binary data, array : which are valid keys.

This error is generally thrown when you are passing - boolean,null or undefined value.

Check out w3c for more info - https://w3c.github.io/IndexedDB/#key-construct

Comment: For others - yes, you can't query null/true/false, you have to first convert them to a string and query for that ...

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who is having this same issue and is actually passing a valid key, it could actually be that you are running.

```
objectStore.put(key, value)
```

when you should run

```
objectStore.put(value, key)
```

It's in reverse by the specs.