# JsStore search for a null value

Tags: indexeddb

In JsStore how can I create a where clause to search for null values, the equivalent of SQL IS NULL?

In IDBStudio the following query does not work and produces an error: 'jsstore.worker.ie.min.b1626280e69a552e8c826a5b2e64196e.js:6 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '!=' of null'

```
select({
from: "OrderDetails",
where: {
    orderId:null
}
});
```

After running this query JsStore seems to break as any further queries do not work (no response at all).  Can anyone help?

Comment: check this out - https://stackoverflow.com/a/48179792/4393136 . Basically null is not a valid key in idb but its a valid value. So you can store it but can not query on it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. In my case I will filter the resulting data for null values if necessary after retrieving it from the IDB.

Comment: What you can do is - convert null to string i.e "null" and then save it. And this way you can query.

Comment: The solution I devised to this problem was to create a library on top of jsstore that acts much the same way Django does with its queries.  So a query like this could be performed as OrderDetail.objects.filter({order_id: null}).  This returns a generator object which, when iterated over, removes any key/value pairs where the value is null and stores the keys in a separate array before executing the query.  Then it uses jsstore to perform the query, and after the query results are retrieved, it skips over any where the key is not null.

Comment: @kloddant yes, you can use plugin approach to create a plugin which will inject a jsstore middleware and return result. 

* plugin doc - https://jsstore.net/tutorial/plugin/
* Middleware doc - https://jsstore.net/tutorial/middleware/

Answer (score 0):

Null is a valid value so you can store data with null value in indexeddb but it is not a valid key, so when you will query for null value. You will get error like - "invalid key supplied".

Please check this out for  more info - [Failed to execute 'only' on 'IDBKeyRange': The parameter is not a valid key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48149851/failed-to-execute-only-on-idbkeyrange-the-parameter-is-not-a-valid-key/48179792#48179792)

So what's the solution ?

Solution is to save null as "null" value, now its a string value. So you can query for it.

Hope this answer your question.

Comment: null may be a valid value in vanilla indexeddb, but using the jsstore library, if I try to query for a null value, I get the error message, "Null/undefined is not allowed in where".